# What is a constructor function's prototype?

Tags: javascript

Say, I have a constructor function called `MyClass`. And I create an object `obj` out of it. `obj` inherits from `MyClass.prototype`. So here is my question:

> Where is the `MyClass.prototype` from? Is it just a plain object with a `constructor` property?

Thanks for your answers.

```
// Constructor
function MyClass() {
}

var obj = new MyClass;

// object inherits from MyClass.prototype
obj.__proto__ == MyClass.prototype;
// => true

// MyClass.prototype inherits from Object.prototype
MyClass.prototype.__proto__ == Object.prototype;
// => true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the `MyClass.prototype` from?

It's [implicitly created](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2) when the function object (`MyClass`) is created.

> Is it just a plain object with a `constructor` property?

Yes, exactly. No more than that, no magic involved :-)

Comment: Bergi ... that is (Y)

Answer (score 0):

- MyClass.prototype is simply a object having constructor method(property).
- as soon as you create object with new operator a protype is also created and the constructor function being called with new operator becomes its property/method